# Changing name bibliography in babel [turkish] is impossible

Tags: bibliographies, babel, turkish

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \usepackage[turkish]{babel}
    \bibliography{dnm2.bib} 
    
    \begin{document}
    some text \cite{abc}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

I tried to change the name of bibliography from references to "Kaynakça" (Same thing in Turkish of course) but fail lots of times.

Comment: Please tell us what you've tried so far. Which document class do you employ? How do you load the `babel` package? (Usually, running `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}` should change the title of the references section to `Kaynaklar`.)

Comment: Which bibliography style/packages do you use?

Comment: I used article document class. and I've seen some advice like

\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliografía}}

for other languages i tried to alter for Turkish but nothing happen.

Comment: please show a small complete document that fails and the log file that you get.

Comment: I experience no problems with `\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Kaynakça}}` -- as long as this instruction is run *after* `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}`.

Comment: i used "\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand{\bibname}{Kaynakça}}" after "\usepackage[turkish]{babel}" but references is still in there.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3):

I succeeded by passing the title directly to `\printbibliography`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{abc,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year=2018,
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addto\captionsturkish{\renewcommand\bibname{Kaynakça}}

\begin{document}

some text \cite{abc}

\printbibliography[title=Kaynakça]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes.

1. There are several incompatibilities between `babel-turkish` and `biblatex`; for instance one has to disable the `=` shorthand. The language is not really supported.
2. Probably the bib items should have a language field, so to avoid the wrong dot above the I.
3. The `filecontents` environment is used just to make the example self-contained.

Comment: I can find an answer from this site somehow from users every time. when i say "i must back to the MS word" someone save me from this stupid idea with knowledge.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @ömerkoçhan You might contact the developers of biblatex in order to give advice for better supporting Turkish: none of them knows the language and they're welcoming helpful people.

Comment: I'd love to help them. Because helping those kinds of smart people equally means helping to myself and other people who try to write useful things.